# Advice for Sturdy harness after Mixed Breed Large Dog broke previous in half

Tags: leashes, large-dogs

My Dog is a large mixed breed, currently at ~80 lbs.  We originally had a MightyPaw harness which we used to secure him to a run (This is temporary until our fence is installed).

He has broken both attachment points on the harness, snapping the metal rings in half.  I've done research on sturdy harnesses, but most results turn up with "Chew-proof" or "Snug fit to prevent escape".  Perhaps I'm missing out on the correct terminology to find what I'm looking for.

Is there terminology which I can use to refine my search, or, failing that, is there a recommendation for a harness that will prevent him from escaping?  It doesn't need to last years, just a few months.  I would have gotten another MightyPaw, but it only took him 3 days to break the previous one.

Comment: I would contact the company and see what they have to say about the failures. Almost sounds you received a defective harness as it should be next to impossible for them to break a harness like that IMO.

Comment: I'll look into it. The only reason I haven't yet is that the harness had a front and back connection and he broke both. I figured the odds of both being faulty were too high. I've found some that will hold for at least a month, so I'll probably remove this question unless it'll help someone else.

Comment: If the two broken points of the harness are identical parts the possibility is high the producer had used an amount of bad parts. Parts often get failure because of misfunction of the production machines. So more than one part will be with failure.